# Generate bitmaps and draw them

Tags: c#, bitmap

How do i generate an image and draw it in C#?
I am generating an image then allowing the user to further modify it by clicking the imagebox.
This is an editor so i shouldn't need any directX? whats the easiest way to generate a bitmap and draw it to screen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the GDI+ libraries found in the System.Drawing, System.Text, System.Printing, System.Internal , System.Imaging, System.Drawing2D and System.Design namespaces.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gdi_plus12092005070041AM/gdi_plus.aspx